# How to use the twitter GeoLocation option in TweetSearch

Tags: social-media

I currently play around with the twitter API and the option GeoLocation in Mathematica version 11.3.

However, the option GeoLocation does not work for me/it does not return anything to me.

What am I doing wrong? The normal request is:

```
In[19]:= twitter["TweetSearch", "Query" -> "#WolframAlpha"]
```

[image: Output]

If I now change it with the option

```
twitter["TweetSearch", "Query" -> "#WolframAlpha", "GeoLocation"]
```

it does not send back anything.

Thanks for any help. Regards Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `ServiceObject` requests take a request name (string) and list of parameters. In this case if you want to extract `GeoLocation` for a set of tweets it seems you'll have to do it like this:

```
tweets =
  twitter["TweetSearch",
   "Query" -> "#WolframAlpha"
   ];

twitter["GetTweet",
     "TweetID" -> #, 
    "Elements" -> "FullData"
    ]["Location"] & /@ Normal@tweets[All, "ID"]

{Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"]}
```

It seems to me that this parameter is of minimal use in general though. I've never seen anything except `Missing`. Also I would have imagined they'd have implemented this in batched form via [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup) request but I guess not.

If you instead want to add a location parameter to your tweet search you can do it like so:

```
loc = FindGeoLocation["255 Elm St, Somerville, MA 02144"];
twitter["TweetSearch",
  "Query" -> "",
  GeoLocation ->loc
 ]
```

[image: blah]